# TypeError: ReactDOM.render is not a function

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am using Enzyme's mount method to test a react component. Getting this error, anyone knows why?

FAIL  src__tests__\components\dashboard\widgets\livenessProbeTest.js (29.386s)
 ? livenessProbe.js > shows correct header

TypeError: ReactDOM.render is not a function

```
 at Object.ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument (node_modules\react\lib\ReactTestUtils.js:76:21)
 at renderWithOptions (node_modules\enzyme\build\react-compat.js:187:26)
 at new ReactWrapper (node_modules\enzyme\build\ReactWrapper.js:94:59)
 at mount (node_modules\enzyme\build\mount.js:19:10)
 at _mountComponent (src\__tests__\components\dashboard\widgets\livenessProbeTest.js:35:10)
 at mountComponent (src\__tests__\components\dashboard\widgets\livenessProbeTest.js:51:12)
 at Object.<anonymous> (src\__tests__\components\dashboard\widgets\livenessProbeTest.js:64:19)
```

Comment: could you pleae add your test code to the question, I assume you are importing `enzyme` and `react-test-renderer` which causes the problem

Comment: I was getting the exact same error with any tests that called `mount`. Once I updated to the latest npm and reinstalled all my modules, the tests were working again.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your packages.

```
npm update
```

material-ui core version 1.3.0 was giving me issues but 1.4.0 is working with mount.